# Why does 64-bit Win7 still warn after having chosen "disable driver signature enforcement"?

Tags: windows, drivers, digital-signature

I have a test driver that must run on 64-bit Windows 7.

According to MSDN, there are two methods to disable OS to check driver's digital signature:

Method 1. Connect the machine to a debugger, such as WinDBG;

Method 2. During booting the machine, hit F8 and choose "disable driver signature enforcement".

I used method 2 to start my OS, and loaded my test driver; however, when the driver was loaded, a message box popped to warn me the driver is unsigned and it will not work. I ignored it, my test driver worked as expected.

My question are:

1. Why did the message box pop under having disabled driver signature enforcement?
2. How to prevent the message box from popping?

Comment: I looked at this a while back and IIRC the only way to prevent this warning message from appearing during the installation of an unsigned driver is to include the driver in your installation media when installing Windows (which is probably no help in your scenario).  The boot option just means that the kernel will allow an installed but unsigned driver to run, I don't think it affects the driver installation process.